# Make it easier to view the markdown of the current revision while a suggested edit is pending

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was reviewing a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10732116) on a post, and I noticed some funny wording that the suggested edit did not remove. Something like "here is the embed code", but there was no code visible. So I looked at the markdown diff trying to find unformatted code, but all I could see was a summary of identical lines skipped.

> [image: Markdown diff]

I tried to go to the original question to examine the markdown, but I couldn't open up the editor, because the suggested edit is still pending.  Eventually, I had to visit the [post's revision page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34536705/revisions) by manually typing in the URL and then view the [source of revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8a64c14f-d8c0-4c1d-86a8-29e2bee817e9/view-source) directly. And yes, there was unformatted markup code that didn't render because of improper indentation.

<strike>Is there something fundamentally easier that I'm missing?  If not, it</strike> A potential workaround is to click Reject and Edit to see the original markdown within the editor (or Improve Edit to see the new suggestion) and then just cancel the additional edit.  But it would be nice to be able to have a more obvious and convenient way to see the full markdown with a checkbox or something in the review diff.  Besides, it's inconvenient to navigate within the editor window just to see the markdown of a long post.

Comment: I thought the bar saying "14 identical lines skipped" was supposed to be clickable to expand the lines that were skipped, but apparently that's only the case on the rendered view? :(

Comment: @animuson you aren't the only one, my good man

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/4274/force-edit-suggested-reviews might be of use to you in this situation.

Comment: @NathanTuggy hmm interesting.  Not sure how I feel about that.

Comment: Also unrelated, maybe I should have put in more effort and clicked Reject and Edit.  Because it was approved.  Wait, I guess I could have clicked that to see the original markdown of the post.  But that's not an obvious solution to this inconvenience.

Comment: @ryanyuyu you can do that right now by hacking the link, the userscript just adds the hacked link to the post.