# Allow "Edit" even if an edit is awaiting approval

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

When I see a post with ill-formatted code, i typically hit `edit` to suggest an edit or just to see what the person pasted in (the input-box doesn't remove linebreaks, tabs, etc.). But I can't do that while another edit is pending, and I'm instead met with a red popup-thingie. The result is that I abandon the post, since it takes time for the pending edit to be reviewed, and it is impossible for me to help if the code is not properly formatted.

It would be great if I could still access the edit page, perhaps from a link in the popup.

Say a user wishes to show some python code, and didn't use "Code sample", then the code will be rendered as HTML-paragraphs (gibberish, as Python is dependant on linebreaks, indents, etc.). However, getting access to the input-field, allows me to see the raw code. If an edit is pending, I can only see the gibberish code. If no edits are pending, I can view the raw code and either format it for the user, or at least inspect the code in an attempt to help.

Example of the difference between code in a textarea and when rendered:
[image: Input vs. rendered]

Comment: How would this help the user experience? You’d be able to see the edit page, but wouldn’t be able to submit or *do* anything. It seems that would be even more frustrating and pointless.

Comment: @CodyGray If you're warned and decide to view the edit-page anyways, in "readonly-mode", then you can at least make sense of the question during the time its current edit is awaiting approval.

Comment: So, perhaps this is a duplicate of this feature request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313716/make-it-easier-to-view-the-markdown-of-the-current-revision-while-a-suggested-ed

Comment: @CodyGray IIRC users under 2k don't get a link to the pending suggested edit at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to be able to see the source of posts, regardless of pending suggested edits, then it's already possible.

You can view the source of any revision of a post by going to the revisions of that post and clicking on the "source" link of that revision.

For instance, on the [revisions of your post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/385963/revisions), the source link of the first revision will link to [this source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/afb46ff0-5df9-40e2-b137-11d703f980ee/view-source).

[image: Image showing the source link on the revisions page]

If there is no link to the revisions yet, you can also go there by manually entering the URL.

```
/posts/[postid]/revisions
```

<sub>Or use a user script that provides a direct link to it.</sub>

Comment: Given the amount of down-votes, I guess this will suffice. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 8):

You can do both of those things *when you've earned the privilege to review edits*.

Comment: Yep.  Just improve the edit, and you can build on the suggested one.

Comment: But why should I earn a badge to see what the author originally input, _while an edit is pending_, when I can open _any_ SO-thread, and hit edit, and see what the author originally input?

Comment: @Jeppe You're not earning a badge, you're earning sufficient reputation to be trusted with the privilege.  What does being able to review pending edits have to do with being able to see previous revisions of a post?  We trust anyone to see the latter, we don't trust everyone to do the former.

Comment: I've removed the small part of my post about reviewing pending edits. My post is about viewing the revisions through clicking `edit`.

Comment: @Jeppe And it's the same privilege.  Also it's considered inappropriate to change a question into a different question after it's been answered, by the way.

Comment: A different question? I removed 5%, half a sentence, _that you chose to focus on_. New contributors have a hard time formatting their code, but through the `edit` "Body" input I can view the authors raw input, with line-breaks, tabs, etc. I'm describing an anti-pattern, since the site does not allow me to view the raw input, but instead formats it to HTML.

Comment: @Jeppe It's not the number of characters, or the percentage of the total post that changes that affects how impactful a change is on what the question is asking.  Most of your question is not actually important to what you're asking.  You removed the one sentence in which you asked your actual question, which, naturally, changed what the question was fundamentally asking.

Comment: I described the problem, _obviously_ this is relevant. I described two possible solutions, as this is a feature request, and you chose to answer one of them, and not address the problem at all.